# Fullcalendar getEventResource example

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

According to the [documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_data/getEventResource/) of getEventResource, I have tried fetching resource based on events but failed to do so.
I also googled for examples relating to getEventResource, but didn't find any concrete answers.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'getEventResource', '17')// Event ID as string
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'getEventResource', 17) // Event ID as integer
```

I have also tried passing the event object, and all the cases returned null.

Can any one give me an example on how to use this method?

Thanks.
EDIT

```
var isValidEvent = function(start,end,divId){
    return 
        $('#div0').fullCalendar('clientEvents', 
                    function(event) {
                        var resourceObj = $('#div0').fullCalendar( 'getEventResource', event);

                        console.log(resourceObj);                     

                        return (event.rendering === "background" && 
                                    (start.isAfter(event.start) || start.isSame(event.start) ) &&
                                    (end.isBefore(event.end) || end.isSame(event.end,'minute')));
                     }).length > 0;
}
```

Even when the object is passed, null is returned.My events are as follows:

```
[
    id: 17,
    title: AAA,
    start: 2016-05-11T03: 00: 00.000-05: 00,
    end: 2016-05-11T07: 30: 00.000-05: 00,
    eventDate: 2016-05-11T03: 00: 00.000-05: 00,
    allDay: false,
    eventType: availability,
    rendering: background,
    color: #F0FFFF,
    resourceIds: [13],
    dow: [3]
]
```

Comment: Are you sure there is an associated resource for the event with id = 17 ? Please provide a small snippet from **resource** x **events** hierarchy.
According to documentation [ http://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_data/getEventResource/ ] it should get results if you are requesting the calendar resources :)

Comment: A little bit strange events mapping to resource... , are your events displayed in calendar when it is loaded ?

Comment: what happens if you map the an `event` to a single `resourceId`. I mean:   
`myEvent = {
                id: 17,
                resourceId: 13,
                start: startDate,
                end: endDate                
                title: 'AAA',
            }`

Will `getEventResource` function return the above event ?

Comment: Ok! So turns out getEventResource doesn't work with multiple resource.
I changed resourceIds to resourceId and  it gave me the resource object as the document suggested.
Thanks @meorfi.

Comment: I posted the answer, according to the comment above, so you can accept and resolve the question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind each `event` to a `resourceId` (not to **`resourceIds`** ).
In this way:

```
myEvent = { id: 17, resourceId: 13, start: startDate, end: endDate title: 'AAA', }
```